# Delete null values in nested javascript objects

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a nested object and want to remove all key/value pairs if the value is null or undefined. I've managed to get the below code working but it doesn't check the nested key/value pairs and wondered if someone could help me figure out what needs adding to the code please?

```
var myObj = {
  fName:'john',
  lName:'doe',
  dob:{
    displayValue: null, 
    value: null
  },
  bbb:null
};

function clean(obj) {
  for (var propName in obj) { 
    if (obj[propName] === null || obj[propName] === undefined || obj[propName] === '') {
      delete obj[propName];
    }
  }
  return obj;
}
console.log(clean(myObj));
```

The above code does the job to remove 'bbb' and its value and I want the same done for the nested object represented by 'dob' as well.

https://jsbin.com/mudirateso/edit?js,console,output

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to write a recursive function that calls `clean()` on any sub-objects.

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 1):

You're already almost there. Just have the function recurse if the property is another object:

```js
var myObj = {
  fName:'john',
  lName:'doe',
  dob:{
    displayValue: null, 
    value: null
  },
  bbb:null
};

function clean(obj) {
  for (var propName in obj) { 
    if (obj[propName] === null || obj[propName] === undefined || obj[propName] === '') {
      delete obj[propName];
    } else if (typeof obj[propName] === "object") {
      // Recurse here if the property is another object.
      clean(obj[propName])
    }
  }
  return obj;
}
console.log(clean(myObj));
```

Comment: But beware of infinite recursion.

Comment: Thank you both!! Much appreciated. @CRice