# JS: Delete Object Key if all nested Values equal null

Tags: javascript, json, object, javascript-objects

From a given data structure (json file) I basically need to render a table. Empty rows and/or columns should not render.  I'm fairly new to JavaScript and tried different approaches (converting to array and using .map(), reduce(), .filter(), lodash etc.) without success. I don't even know what the best way would be to tackle the problem. (Or what possible search terms would be.)

Neither "row keys" (In example: mo, tu, we, th, fr) nor "column keys" (john, hane, doe) are known and can vary.

Complete example: https://jsbin.com/rafeyasena/edit?js,output

```
"groupA": {
    "mo": { "john": 8, "jane": 5, "doe": null },
    "tu": { "john": 8, "jane": 5, "doe": null },
    "we": { "john": 5, "jane": 9, "doe": null },
    "th": { "john": 6, "jane": 3, "doe": null },
    "fr": { "john": null, "jane": null, "doe": null }
  }
```

Possible resulting data structure

```
const header = ["John", "Jane"];
const content = [
 "mo": {[ 8, 5 ]},
 "tu": {[ 8, 5 ]},
 "we": {[ 5, 9 ]},
 "th": {[ 6, 3 ]}
]
```

Expected result (Front-end, React):

```
   | John | Jane |
---|------|--------
mo |  8   |  5   |
tu |  8   |  5   |
we |  5   |  9   |
th |  6   |  3   |
```

What I tried so far:
I was able to delete all values of null and the corresponding key, if it doesn't contain keys/values any more ([Delete null values in nested javascript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296396/delete-null-values-in-nested-javascript-objects)) - leading me with the challenge to find out all the leftover keys to build the table header. (In the example below this would be only John and Jane - So basically a way to iterate over all keys and log each key that exists at least one time). So my current data looks like this (but I'm not sure if it is the best way):

```
"groupA": {
    "mo": { "john": 8, "jane": 5, },
    "tu": { "john": 8, "jane": 5, },
    "we": { "john": 5, "jane": 9, },
    "th": { "john": 6, "jane": 3, }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just represent the data as a 2D array (that makes rendering easier):

```
 const columnNames = [""];
 const rows = [columnNames];

  for(const [rowName, values] of Object.entries(groupA)) {
     const row = [rowName];
     for(const [columnName, value] of Object.entries(values)) {
        let position = columnNames.indexOf(columnName);
        if(value === null) continue;
        if(position === -1)
          position = columnNames.push(columnName) - 1;
        row[position] = value;
     }
     rows.push(row);
 }

 // just some debugging:   
 console.log( rows.map(row => row.map(it => (it || "").padStart(10)).join("|")).join("\n") );
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is way more compact than everything I would have been able to write. Figured out array destructuring for the first time. I try to get my head around the "let position = columnNames.indexOf(columnName)" part. Currently the code still outputs empty rows (without any values in it) - but that should be easy to fix.

Thanks so much for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

I think creating that latter format (with the nulls removed) is a very useful first step.  From there you could write something like this to get it into a variant of your target format:

```js
const uniqKeys = (obj) => [... new Set(Object.values(obj).flatMap(Object.keys))]

const transform = (group, headers = uniqKeys(group)) => ({
  headers,
  content: Object.entries(group).reduce(
    (a, [k, v]) => ({...a, [k]: headers.map(h => v[h])}),
    {}
  )
})


const groupA = {mo: {john: 8, jane: 5}, tu: {john: 8, jane: 5}, we: {john: 5, jane: 9}, th: {john: 6, jane: 3}}

console.log(transform(groupA))
```

Note that the target is a little different than your request, as your example content isn't legal JS (`{[ 8, 5 ]}` doesn't make sense) but I think it captures the spirit of it, returning something like:

```
{
  headers: ['john', 'jane'],
  content: {
    mo: [8, 5],
    tu: [8, 5],
    we: [5, 9],
    th: [6, 3]
  }
}
```

Note that this function is a little more general than the requirements, as you could supply it a list of headers and only extract those from the data.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). It makes this sort of this relatively easy once you wrap your head around how it works. Here is how you'd answer your questions

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const isNullObject = (obj) => (
  obj instanceof Object
  && !Array.isArray(obj)
  && Object.values(obj).every((e) => e === null)
);

const prune = (data) => objectScan(['**'], {
  rtn: 'count',
  filterFn: ({ value, parent, property }) => {
    if (isNullObject(value)) {
      delete parent[property];
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
})(data);

const stats = { groupA: { mo: { john: 8, jane: 5, doe: null }, tu: { john: 8, jane: 5, doe: null }, we: { john: 5, jane: 9, doe: null }, th: { john: 6, jane: 3, doe: null }, fr: { john: null, jane: null, doe: null } } };

console.log(prune(stats)); // return number of replaces
// => 1

console.log(stats);
/* =>
  { groupA:
    { mo: { john: 8, jane: 5, doe: null },
      tu: { john: 8, jane: 5, doe: null },
      we: { john: 5, jane: 9, doe: null },
      th: { john: 6, jane: 3, doe: null } } }
*/
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)